# How to make TCP/IP connection in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-xe2

I have to develop a simple application in Delphi XE2. This application will connect to a service running on a server with IP Address(say xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) with some Port No (say xxxx) using TCP/IP protocol and will get reply from the service running on the server.

I have created two textboxes: txtRequestMsg, txtReplyMsg and a button called Connect.

I need to open a TCP connection and send some data and get some data back in response, something like a ping, but not using ICMP, just raw TCP.

Comment: I asume ping in your case means testing to connect to a IP/port, you couls search for INDY or TCPClient

Comment: thanks, to ping, I mean connect. Can you give me some for detail about INDY or TCPClient?

Comment: Have you read the Indy documentation and tried any of the Indy examples? Or would you like us to do that for you?

Comment: -1. There are dozens of results on a Google search for `Delphi Internet` and `Delphi TCP/IP`, and there are highly visible (and well known) Indy components in Delphi's component palette. This question shows zero effort to research this problem yourself by even a basic search.

Comment: For future reference "give me some codez" is considered rude on Stack Overflow.  It's better to show that you've made an effort than to say "do my thinking and my research for me".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most commonly used Delphi internet libraries that provide TCP and UDP components for various TCP client (originating) and TCP server (answering) protocols are:

1. Indy version 10, which is included in the box with your Delphi XE2 installation. Almost any of the [demos](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx) would probably give you enough information to get started, but be prepared to read documentation, too. Nobody is going to teach you in a single stack overflow question how to write network applications. There are MANY people on Stackoverflow who use this library, and an Indy team member is often on here and answers questions about Indy, and it's well respected, and unless you have a real reason not to use it, you should probably start with Indy.  Ask specific questions about Indy when you've tried something, rather than vague questions like this one, please.
2. [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html) by Francois Piette.  I like it because the code is smaller and simpler and I find it easier to use than Indy, but fewer people use it.  There are people on Stackoverflow who use this library, including me, and Francois himself who is active here on SO.
3. Synapse. I have only used this a bit, but I know lots of people use it.